# Remove duplicate rows based on particular field

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a table with data similar to this:

```
stat_id    account_id    discount    date_from    date_to    type
1          1             50          2017-10-01   2017-10-31 1
2          2             40          2017-10-01   2017-10-31 1
3          1             0           2017-01-01   2017-11-30 2
```

I want to get all distinct `account_id`s, for a given period (`date_from <= '2017-10-01' and date_to >= '2017-10-31'`), each one with the highest `type` (`type` is either 1 or 2)

```
account_id    discount    type
1             0           2
2             40          1
```

I tried various queries, but I couldn't achieve this. What I get is one row with `type = 1` and one row with `type = 2` for `account_id = 1`

```
account_id    discount    type
1             50          1
1             0           2
2             40          1
```

I can filter them in my application, but for pure personal entertainment I want to do it in one query. Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
SELECT account_id, discount, type
FROM YOUR_TABLE 
WHERE (account_id, type) IN (SELECT account_id, MAX(type)
                             FROM YOUR_TABLE
                             GROUP BY account_id)
AND date_from <= '2017-10-01' 
AND date_to >= '2017-10-31'
```